# dont allow user access joomla catalog using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a joomla website with article url like: http:// domain .com/catalog/article.html

The web allow user access url: http:// domain .com/catalog/article.html

but don't allow url: http:// domain .com/catalog/ or http:// domain .com/catalog.html

I try use htaccess but it's not work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  =http:// domain .com/catalog/ 
RewriteRule /catalog/ http:// domain .com/
```

Thank you

Note:
because the catalog have ~200.000 articles. Server is down when user list articles of this catalog like request url: http:// domain .com/catalog/

Is there any like this:

```
If (url==http:// domain .com/catalog/){
   #redirect homepage
}else {
   #do nothing, allow users access the url
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide some examples.

Comment: I try allow users access a article in the catalog BUT deny list articles of catalog

Comment: So which URL you want to block? Do you want block `http://domain.com/catalog/` URL?

Comment: Yes. http:// domain .com/catalog, http:// domain .com/catalog/, http:// domain .com/catalog.html must be block or redirect to homepage

Comment: ok provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^catalog(\.html|/)?$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: No this rule blocks `/catalog/` also unless there is a .htaccess in `/catalog/` directory. Also make sure this is your first and rule and you test in a new browser to avoid previous caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog(/|\.html)$ error_page.php [L]
```